# Which one is correct 考えながら or 考ながら

Tags: grammar, verbs

In Tobira Chapter 14, one of the examples says
漢字を書く時は、文字のバラスもよく考ながら、点や線をきちんと書いて下さい。

According to the usage of ながら: verb stem + ながら. But 考える's verb stem is 考え. Why is 考ながら used instead?

Answer (score 1):

If that's the way it is in the textbook, then your textbook has an error. As you correctly observed, 〜ながら is meant to attach to the stem, which is 考え in the case of 考える.

Also, I assume you meant バランス rather than バラス as written in the original post.

Comment: Thank you! Now I found a typo, at least in my version of Tobira.